# event.target element losing parent node information

Tags: javascript, dom, event-propagation

I'm trying to use javascript's `closest` function on an `event.target` element, but it appears that the `event.target` loses its parent information from the DOM?

[image]

FWIW - I'm detecting clicks on outside of an element body to determine whether or not to close the element.

```
const hideOnClickOutside = (tag, selector) => {
    const isVisible = (element) => {
        return element.offsetWidth > 0 || element.offsetHeight > 0;
    }

    const outsideClickListener = (e) => {
        // HERE!!
        if (!e.target.closest(selector) && e.target.nodeName != 'BUTTON') {
            const element = document.querySelector(selector);
            if (isVisible(element)) {
                tag.update({visible: false});
                document.removeEventListener('click', outsideClickListener);
            }
        }
    }

    document.addEventListener('click', outsideClickListener);
}
```

#### EDIT:

I appears that a prior event firing has updated the DOM, so the original element `e.target` no longer exists. So I guess the question becomes, how do I associate `e.target` to the new DOM element that took its place? Using `Riotjs` with nested components attaching multiple click events.

#### EDIT 2:

So if you look in the screenshot, the `td` element has a different class than the `e.target` element, suggesting the `td` elements have in fact been replaced.

I can verify this behavior in https://jsfiddle.net/dainovu3/xuLweLuj/ with a very contrived example that would mimick triggering a re-rendering of the DOM in riot.js whatever other framework.

So... I want to access the parent element of the e.target up the chain of the propogation.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://jsfiddle.net/2mpd7wLq/). You'll have to post an example that shows the behaviour.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle or a snippet(preferable) and give us the Browser you're using? Be aware that .closest is still experimental so it may not work as well as you hope everywhere.

Comment: yes, gents, I will attempt to reproduce.

Comment: Good deal. A **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem, using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button), will make it easy to help you.

Comment: OK, updated the question with a fiddle that simulates my situation and the suspected issue.

Answer (score 1):

The `event.target` for the second listener is still the original node, not the clone, and by the time that listener runs it's already been removed from the DOM and has no parent anymore.

Here's the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xuLweLuj/2/). If you want to use the clone, you'll have to query the DOM for it in the listener.

Comment: Soooo... thank you, I appreciate the help, but I need an intelligent way of finding the new node by referencing the old because any number of event handlers could have manipulated the old node... simple `document.querySelect('td')` is insufficient given it's a datepicker with hundreds of 'dt' nodes.... I have to believe there are elegant ways of maintaining a reference to a stale node's position on a stale DOM...

Comment: @daino there is not such a method. Removing a node from the DOM like that eliminates any of that information so that it does not prevent garbage collection. Also for that reason doing so without removing the listeners on the element is a memory leak. Why do you have to remove the node from the DOM anyway?

Comment: Gotcha. I actually approached the problem from a different angle. We're using a clear html backdrop and adding the event listener on that, so we don't have to detect whether or not the click event happened inside a parent div... a modal approach which seems to work... thanks for the help!

Comment: @JaredSmith what are the steps involved in querying the DOM for the clone?

Comment: @NikolaiHegelstad rather than using `event.target` give your element something unique (like an ID) and query the DOM for that with `document.querySelector`.